# How to stop timer when user goes back to previous view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nstimer

I have problem with my timer.
In my game view in `viewDidLoad` I have:

```
sixtySecondTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/1.0) target:self selector:@selector(changeValue) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Next I have changeValue method:

```
- (void) changeValue {
    timerInt += 1;
    NSLog(@"TimerInt2 = %d", timerInt);
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", timerInt];
    labelTimer.text = string;
}
```

And I go to previous view using:

```
- (IBAction)backView:(id)sender {
    timerInt = 0;
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

When I am in previous view in command line I can see:

```
2012-02-13 10:04:33.393 Colores[1240:707] TimerInt2 = 1
2012-02-13 10:04:34.393 Colores[1240:707] TimerInt2 = 2
2012-02-13 10:04:35.393 Colores[1240:707] TimerInt2 = 3
```

And when I go to game view in command line I can see this:

```
2012-02-13 10:04:36.393 Colores[1240:707] TimerInt2 = 4
2012-02-13 10:04:36.508 Colores[1240:707] TimerInt2 = 1
2012-02-13 10:04:37.393 Colores[1240:707] TimerInt2 = 5
2012-02-13 10:04:37.508 Colores[1240:707] TimerInt2 = 2
2012-02-13 10:04:38.393 Colores[1240:707] TimerInt2 = 6
2012-02-13 10:04:38.508 Colores[1240:707] TimerInt2 = 3
```

Problem is that my timer don't stop and when I go again to game view create "new" variable timerInt... When I go again to previous view and again go to game view then I have three timerInt variable.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    - (IBAction)backView:(id)sender {
      if ([sixtySecondTimer isValid])
{ 
      [sixtySecondTimer invalidate];
        timerInt = 0;
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

sending `invalidate` to a timer stops it from firing again

Answer (score 1):

You should to invalidate timer before going to the previous controller use this:

```
 - (IBAction)backView:(id)sender 
{
       if ([sixtySecondTimer isValid])
        {
           [sixtySecondTimer invalidate];
           sixtySecondTimer = nil;
       }
        timerInt = 0;

        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop timer when view is not visible to you, you should `invalidateTimer` into `viewDidDisappear` method. If you want to stop timer only when that controller is out of hierarchy, you should `invalidateTimer` into `dealloc` method.