# iOS - Execute a Piece of Code for 10 Seconds

Tags: objective-c, ios, nstimer

I'd like to execute a piece of code every 500ms for a total of 10 seconds. I have the code working executing every half a second with this code

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(getLevel:) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
```

but I cannot seem to figure out how to stop it executing after 10 seconds. The "repeats" argument doesnt seem to allow for a specified time. 
Could someone point me in the direction of where I should go with this?

Thanks
Brian

Comment: Would [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9258071/264775) answer apply?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to message `invalidate` on the NSTimer that scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats: gives you. For example assign the NSTimer that method returns to you in a property or iVar of your class and after 10 seconds call `invalidate` on it.

Example:

.h:

```
@interface myClass{
NSTimer *myT;
}
[...]
```

.m:

```
[...]
{
    myT = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(getLevel:) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(stop) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(void)stop{
    [myT invalidate];
}
[...]
```

You could avoid another `NSTimer` if you want by implementing some kind of `finish` flag and track how many times you messaged the `getLevel` method, since it's every .5 seconds, that'll be 20 times.

But I would rather 2 `NSTimer` objects because you know it's 10 seconds regardless of the other timer, which you might decide to change, up or down it's frequency...

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is make a property on your class.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) int ticks;
```

then in your getLevel selector call this:

```
if (ticks >= 20) [self.timer invalidate];
// 20 is 10 seconds * 500 milliseconds
ticks++;
```

Comment: There are only 20 500ms in 10 seconds, not 5000 and the if statement should be if (ticks == 20) not >20.

Answer (score 1):

Another way you could go would be to define a selector, say `-(void)stopTimer{}`
in which you invalidate the timer.  Then when you create the Timer in the first place do one of these:

`[self performSelector:@selector(stopTimer) withObject:nil afterDelay:10.0];`

Answer (score 0):

You can set another timer to stop it using invalidate. Just keep a reference for this timer in an ivar or property.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862743/pausing-an-nstimer) for more information.